Can I change the owning user of a volume mount in cloud run?
I have a cloud run instance that with a volume mount that mounts a storage bucket into the filesystem. By default the volume mount is owned by root and/or a user with uid -1 (the docs seem to imply both things.)
The docs documentation mentions that volume mounts are powered by FUSE And the FUSE options mention you can mount the directory with a particular user as the owner. (--uid)
Can I edit the yaml file to force my volume mount to be mounted as a particular user somehow? Is there another option to create a filesystem mount with a given user that wouldn't cost me more then like 10 bucks a month?

Since this post is not related to programming, it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It might be on-topic in [sf] or DevOps.

Yes,there is. First check /etc/fstab,if you r user is ther it will mount on the boot.

What's your use case? Usually, the disk is mount as root, and then you can change permission on subdir/file (chmod/chown). But Why?

If you are running an application in Cloud Run, why are you implementing concepts such as users? Cloud Storage has no concept of Linux file ownership or Linux permissions. Why implement anything that is just an emulation? You are just adding additional processing and latency for no real value. If your use case requires users, document that so that you get a proper answer.

Yes, you can pass flags to gcsfuse using the volume attribute mountOptions in the yaml as described in this section of the docs.
